# Find command in python catches only first line

Tags: python, find, text-manipulation

Trying to grab the magnet link from the following code

```
rawdata = ''' <div class="iaconbox center floatright">
            <a rel="12624681,0" class="icommentjs kaButton smallButton rightButton" href="https://kat.cr/zootopia-2016-1080p-hdrip-x264-ac3-jyk-t12624681.html#comment">209 <i class="ka ka-comment"></i></a>               <a class="icon16" href="https://kat.cr/zootopia-2016-1080p-hdrip-x264-ac3-jyk-t12624681.html" title="Verified Torrent"><i class="ka ka16 ka-verify ka-green"></i></a>                                <div data-sc-replace="" data-sc-slot="_ae58c272c09a10c792c6b17d55c20208" class="none" data-sc-params="{ &#39;name&#39;: &#39;Zootopia%202016%201080p%20HDRip%20x264%20AC3-JYK&#39;, &#39;extension&#39;: &#39;mkv&#39;, &#39;magnet&#39;: &#39;magnet:?xt=urn:btih:CE8357DED670F06329F6028D2F2CEA6F514646E0&amp;dn=zootopia+2016+1080p+hdrip+x264+ac3+jyk&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&#39; }"></div>
            <a data-nop="" title="Torrent magnet link" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:CE8357DED670F06329F6028D2F2CEA6F514646E0&amp;dn=zootopia+2016+1080p+hdrip+x264+ac3+jyk&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce" class="icon16 askFeedbackjs" data-id="CE8357DED670F06329F6028D2F2CEA6F514646E0"><i class="ka ka16 ka-magnet"></i></a>
            <a data-download="" title="Download torrent file" href="https://kat.cr/torrents/zootopia-2016-1080p-hdrip-x264-ac3-jyk-t12624681/" class="icon16 askFeedbackjs"><i class="ka ka16 ka-arrow-down"></i></a>
        </div> '''
```

Using this command

```
rawdata[rawdata.find("<")+1:rawdata.find(">")]
```

Gives me

> div class="iaconbox center floatright"

But when I try to find Magnet link

```
rawdata[rawdata.find("href="magnet:?")+1:rawdata.find(""")]
```

It gives me

> '    '

What I actually want it to give me

> magnet:?xt=urn:btih:CE8357DED670F06329F6028D2F2CEA6F514646E0&dn=zootopia+2016+1080p+hdrip+x264+ac3+jyk&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce

It's so easy with Shell, but it has to be done with Python itself.

Answer (score 1):

try `rawdata[rawdata.find('href="magnet:?')+1:rawdata.find('"')]`

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use regular expression.

```
import re

rawdata = '''your rawdata......'''
regex = re.compile('href="(.+)" class="icon16')
magnet_href = regex.search(rawdata).group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as pointed out by HenryM, you need to use single quotes or escape the `"` to make the strings valid.

Second, `find()` always returns the first index of the character found. So you will find the first `"` and not the one ending the link. To fix this use the `beg` parameter to define the beginning of your search.

Additionally, you need to add the length of your query to the start index, as `find` gives you the starting index of the match, not the end you are looking for. The code would look something like this (completely untested):

```
start = rawdata.find('href="magnet:?') + 14
end = rawdata.find('"', beg=start)
link = rawdata[start:end]
```

Answer (score 1):

The input data is an HTML fragment. [You should not be using regular expressions to parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Use a parser instead. Here is a working sample using [`BeautifulSoup` HTML parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


rawdata = ''' <div class="iaconbox center floatright">
    <a rel="12624681,0" class="icommentjs kaButton smallButton rightButton" href="https://kat.cr/zootopia-2016-1080p-hdrip-x264-ac3-jyk-t12624681.html#comment">209 <i class="ka ka-comment"></i></a>               <a class="icon16" href="https://kat.cr/zootopia-2016-1080p-hdrip-x264-ac3-jyk-t12624681.html" title="Verified Torrent"><i class="ka ka16 ka-verify ka-green"></i></a>                                <div data-sc-replace="" data-sc-slot="_ae58c272c09a10c792c6b17d55c20208" class="none" data-sc-params="{ &#39;name&#39;: &#39;Zootopia%202016%201080p%20HDRip%20x264%20AC3-JYK&#39;, &#39;extension&#39;: &#39;mkv&#39;, &#39;magnet&#39;: &#39;magnet:?xt=urn:btih:CE8357DED670F06329F6028D2F2CEA6F514646E0&amp;dn=zootopia+2016+1080p+hdrip+x264+ac3+jyk&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&#39; }"></div>
    <a data-nop="" title="Torrent magnet link" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:CE8357DED670F06329F6028D2F2CEA6F514646E0&amp;dn=zootopia+2016+1080p+hdrip+x264+ac3+jyk&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&amp;tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce" class="icon16 askFeedbackjs" data-id="CE8357DED670F06329F6028D2F2CEA6F514646E0"><i class="ka ka16 ka-magnet"></i></a>
    <a data-download="" title="Download torrent file" href="https://kat.cr/torrents/zootopia-2016-1080p-hdrip-x264-ac3-jyk-t12624681/" class="icon16 askFeedbackjs"><i class="ka ka16 ka-arrow-down"></i></a>
</div> '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(rawdata, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("a", title="Torrent magnet link")["href"])
```

Prints:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:CE8357DED670F06329F6028D2F2CEA6F514646E0&dn=zootopia+2016+1080p+hdrip+x264+ac3+jyk&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.publicbt.com%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fglotorrents.pw%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A80%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce
```

Comment: If I were to find multiple instances of the Magnet link, will findall() do the job here?

Comment: @SamFlynn yeas, sure, use the `find_all()` method and get the `href` attribute for every element found in the loop.